# R iGraph remove vertices with attribute value = NA

Tags: r, igraph, na

I'm trying to remove all vertices from a graph which have the value "NA" in the attribute "concreteness". I've tried using the following code:

```
G.concrete <- delete.vertices(g, V(g)$concreteness[V(g)$concreteness, value = "NA"])
```

but no luck.

For example if we take the concreteness values to be:

```
concreteness <- c(NA, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, NA, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)
```

And then set them as attributes using:

```
g <- make_ring(10) %>%
set_vertex_attr("concreteness", value = concreteness)
```

We would have two vertices which would need to be removed. These `"NA"` values register as `"TRUE"` when queried using `is.na()`.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all vertices with NA values for concreteness you can do

```
V(g)[is.na(concreteness)]
```

and to delete them, use

```
delete.vertices(g, V(g)[is.na(concreteness)])
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This works fine for my data, but out of curiosity I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without referring to the "concreteness" vector?

Comment: It's actually not using the concreteness vector, it's using the attribute values. See the "vertex attribute" part of: https://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph-vs-indexing.html. You can verify this by changing the name of the vector but keeping the attribute name the same.